# resetting fill color in d3

Tags: jquery, svg, d3.js

I'm using d3 to create a globe. I want to change the fill color of the countries depending on whether they are in an array called "unrepresented". But I can't get the fill color to change. Do I have the wrong syntax, please?

```
d3.json("world-countries.json", function(collection) {

         feature = svg.selectAll("path")
              .data(collection.features)
              .enter().append("svg:path")
              .attr("d", clip)
              .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; })
              .on("mouseover", pathOver)
              .on("mouseout", pathOut)
              .on("click", click);

          feature.append("svg:title")
              .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });

          feature.each(function(){
            thisOne = $(this).attr('id');
             for (var i=0; i<unrepresented.length; i++){
                if ($(this).attr('id') == unrepresented[i]) {
                    thisOne.style("fill", "#000000");;
                }
             }
          });


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thisOne` is the ID of node in your code -- you can't set a style on that. The following code should work:

```
d3.select(this).style("fill", "#000000");
```

Comment: I made that change, but now it throws the error: Error: Problem parsing d=""

Comment: That's an unrelated error. Could you post a complete working example please?

Comment: No, there's something else wrong with my code. Your answer is right. Thanks, Lars!